# SQL query to add column that counts number of encounters for the past year from each encounter

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to identify High-Usage status for customers, so at time of order how many orders did the customer place in the last year. Each customer has unique ID and each order has unique ID, with a date/time stamp at time of order. This is not just adding a count column, but a conditional count. I can recreate this in Excel using sumproduct, but wanted to see if I can automate the process in SMSS before my pull.

I tried a subquery column and then doing a join on a subquery result:

```sql
SELECT (*)
,HU_CUSTOMER_YOY
FROM data
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_ID
          ,COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) AS HU_CUSTOMER_YOY
          FROM data AS CUS_HU
          WHERE ORDER_DTTM > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, ORDER_DTTM)
          GROUP BY CUS_HU.CUSTOMER_ID) 
          CUSHU on CUSHU.ORDER_ID = data.ORDER_ID
```

This pulls in a value ONLY on the most recent order and counts ALL previous orders. To reiterate, I need a value on EACH unique order to count every order for that customer for the previous year from that unique order. My issue is using the DTTM column. If I use a static date like getdate(), it will count but I need the count for the DTTM-1year on EACH order to view historical data, i.e., when a customer began and fell-off High-Usage status, what contributed to the change, etc.

This is for a rather large dataset that is refreshed daily. I would prefer to not have the main query be aggregated, if possible, which is why I thought creating and joining a reference table would be preferred.

Is this possible?

Adding expected query results:

| customer_id | order_id | HU_count | order_dttm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c1 | c1-1 | 0 | 1/1/2020 |
| c1 | c1-2 | 1 | 7/1/2020 |
| c1 | c1-3 | 0 | 1/1/2022 |
| c1 | c1-4 | 1 | 1/10/2022 |
| c2 | c2-1 | 0 | 1/11/2022 |
| c1 | c1-5 | 2 | 1/14/2022 |
| c2 | c2-2 | 1 | 1/15/2022 |

Comment: I have *assumed* you are using SQL Server here. If you are using a different product that you can connect to use SSMS, such as Azure SQL Edge, AZure SQL Database, etc, then please [edit] your question to correct the tag(s).

Comment: An APPLY operation could do this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using SQL Server from your usage of the DATEADD function.

Based on my understanding of the requirements, this will show the count for each order for each customer in the previous year.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
customer_id as hu_customer_yoy
,COUNT(case when order_dttm > DATEADD(YEAR, -1, order_dttm) THEN 1 ELSE null END) 
  over (partition by customer_id, order_id) AS ORDER_COUNT 
,ORDER_ID
FROM data
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server, yes. So I have done something similar, partitioning by both customer and order ID results in a count of 1 for each entry, whereas partitioning by customer ID only results in an overall order over the life of the customer, not limited to 1 year from order.